# help to understand "the other extreme where his hair was concerned"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Hagrid was sitting at his table, where there were two large mugs of tea. He looked a real mess. His face was blotchy, his eyes swollen, and he had gone to **the other extreme where his hair was concerned**; far from trying to make it behave, it now looked like a wig of tangled wire.

I'm not sure if I understand that part correctly. In my opinion, the word 'concern' here means 'worry'. So, it can be rephrased as: *he had gone to the other extreme at which his hair was worried*.

But I really don't know if I get it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Potter books are written in a colloquial version of British English, which does not make for the easiest comprehension by those learning English or even by native speakers of an English dialect other than British English.

The stock phrase "the other extreme" indicates one end of a range of possible states.

"Jane, the tallest girl in the school, had inexplicably chosen a boyfriend at the other extreme. John was unusually short. The meaner girls referred to the pair as Lady Giraffe and Sir Shrimp."

"Concern" here is not used in the sense or "worry" but rather in the neutral sense of "relate to." Thus, "to the other extreme where his hair was concerned" just means that Hagrid's hair was very far from its usual state. It does not mean that Hagrid's hair was capable of being worried.

Comment: It sounds like:  *he had gone to the other extreme as far as his hair was concerned.*

Comment: Yes. That is what it means.

Comment: Is it not a little unusual for **other extreme** to be  cataphoric as it is here, looking ahead to "trying to make it behave"?  I would have expected *and far from trying to make his hair behave, he had gone to the other extreme: it now looked like a wig of tangled wire*

Comment: I agree that the sentence as a whole is odd. It switches from Hagrid trying to make his hair behave to a final clause in which Hagrid's hair has replaced Hagrid as the subject. I elected not to digress on that point because I have found from experience that going beyond the defined scope of any question about the Harry Potter books is a losing proposition.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I don't think it's meant to be cataphoric. I think it's referring back to something from a few chapters earlier: *Hagrid was wearing his best (and very horrible) hairy brown suit, plus a checked yellow-and-orange tie. This wasn't the worst of it, though; he had evidently tried to tame his hair, using large quantities of what appeared to be axle grease. It was now slicked down into two bunches — perhaps he had tried a ponytail like Bill's, but found he had too much hair. The look didn't really suit Hagrid at all.* It's saying he had gone to the other extreme of what he had done earlier

Comment: @dan See above, if that part of the sentence was also confusing to you.